# GraphicTracker what to use for IGeometry? ArcObjects

Tags: arcobjects

```
IGraphicTrackerSymbol myPointSymbol = graphicTracker.CreateSymbolFromPath("Z:/ESRI/sprites/car.jpg", "");
graphicTracker.Add(null /* what to put here for IGeometry?? */, myPointSymbol);
```

Where can I get the IGeometry of my sprite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the CreateSymbolFromPath function doesn't support jpgs.  I gave it a bmp and it works fine. It's the little things that kill ya.  Btw. you just need a regular point for the function.